# What is the number of disk cylinders in a disk?

Tags: disk-space, disk-structures

A disk has the following characteristics :

- bytes per sector = 512
- sectors per track = 50
- tracks per surface = 2000
- number of platters = 5
- average rotational speed =5400 rpm
- average seek time = 10 ms

What is the number of disk cylinders ?

Isn't it one whole cylinder like the following screenshot seems to show or is cylinder a synonym of platter ?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about hardware, not about database administration

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name shouldn't it be migrated to superuser according to [this meta answer from Gnoupi](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57998/hardware-questions-and-stack-exchange) therfore ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this Wiki post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector) - highlighting mine:

> *Cylinders*
>
> A cylinder is a division of data in a disk drive, as used in the CHS
>   addressing mode of a Fixed Block Architecture disk or the
>   cylinder–head–record (CCHHR) addressing mode of a CKD disk.
>
> The concept is concentric, hollow, cylindrical slices through the
>   physical disks (platters), collecting the respective circular tracks
>   aligned through the stack of platters. **The number of cylinders of a
>   disk drive exactly equals the number of tracks on a single surface in
>   the drive.** It comprises the same track number on each platter,
>   spanning all such tracks across each platter surface that is able to
>   store data (without regard to whether or not the track is "bad").
>   Cylinders are vertically formed by tracks. In other words, track 12 on
>   platter 0 plus track 12 on platter 1 etc. is cylinder 12.

Conceptually, a cylinder is "standing on top of one track and looking straight down through all of the platters."
If you have 2000 tracks, you have 2000 cylinders.